# Asymptotic analysis of a ratio

Tags: computer-science, asymptotics

Is $ \frac{n^2}{n-2}\in O(n) $ true? Intuitively it seems so but how would I rigorously prove this?

Comment: You just need to find $K$ so that for sufficiently large $n$ your function is bounded by $K*n$. It diesn't have to be true immediately for small $n$, and the constant $K$ can be as big as you want for your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ \frac{n^2}{n-2} = n+\frac{2n}{n-2} \leq n+2n= 3n \,,$$

since $ \frac{n}{n-2}<n\,, \forall n > 2 $

Comment: The constant 3 cannot be improved on, if the inequality is to hold for all $n>2$ This is clear since $3^2/(3-2)=9=3*3$.

Answer (score 1):

Simplify $\frac{n^2}{n-2}$ into $\frac{n^2 - 4}{n-2} + \frac{4}{n-2} = \frac{(n+2)(n-2)}{n-2} + \frac{4}{n-2} = n + 2 + \frac{4}{n-2} \leq n + 6$. Then, as long as $n \geq 6$, $\frac{n^2}{n-2} \leq 2n$, so $\frac{n^2}{n-2} \in O(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition (when $\,n\to\infty\,$ in this case, of course)

$$\frac{n^2}{n-2}=\mathcal O(n)\Longleftrightarrow\,\exists\,K\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t.\;\; \left|\frac{\frac{n^2}{n-2}}{n}\right|=\left|\frac{n^2}{n^2-2n}\right|\leq K$$

when $\,n\to\infty\,$ , and since $\,\displaystyle{\frac{n^2}{n^2-2n}\xrightarrow [n\to\infty]{} 1}\,$ , we're done.